# Remove duplicate values appearing in different columns, not in the same order

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

I am trying to consolidate data in a graph-like table. Basically, I have transitions between vertices with some values, and I want to retrieve unique pairs of vertices in the same row, with edge values appearing as columns. For each of the pairs I have two records: transition from **A** edge to **B** edge, and transition from **B** edge to **A** edge, and I want to consolidate them into one row.

I'll try to explain it by example.

Let's say that I have a table with the following structure:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    A    |    B    |    1    |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    B    |    A    |    2    |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    A    |    C    |    3    |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    C    |    A    |    4    |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
```

and I want my final output to be:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    A    |    B    |    1    |    2    |
|    A    |    C    |    3    |    4    |
```

The query I am using is giving me the proper structure, but I have the problem with the duplicate records:

```
SELECT
    t.column1, t.column2, t.column3, t2.column3 as column4
FROM my_table t INNER JOIN my_table t2
  ON t.column1=t2.column2 AND t.column2=t2.column1;
```

and this is what my results look like:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    A    |    B    |    1    |    2    |
|    A    |    C    |    3    |    4    |
|    B    |    A    |    2    |    1    |
|    C    |    A    |    4    |    3    |
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this problem, or remove duplicate records?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Okay, I have just updated tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases support the `least()` and `greatest()` functions.  With these, you can do:

```
select least(column1, column2) as column1,
       greatest(column1, column2) as column2,
       min(column3) as column3,
       (case when min(column3) <> max(column3) then max(column3) end) as column4
from my_table t
group by least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2);
```

Comment: `column4` does not exist in the source table.